# JavaScript search() fails to find "()"

Tags: javascript, search

This might seem trivial, but I'm new to JS. I have this piece of code:

```
alert(elementAction);    
var argumentsBegin = elementAction.search("(");
var argumentsEnd = elementAction.search(")");
alert(argumentsBegin);
```

`elementAction` is a string. The problem with the code is it doesn't seem to find the parenthesis. The first alert box shows for example:
`outer(inner)`
But the second one doesn't appear at all. All is cool if I replace () with {}, though. Any thoughts why is this not working for me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Try `var arg = elementAction.match(/\\([^)]*\\)/);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes: the `search()` method of strings expects a regular expression as the parameter and is treating the string you're passing as a regular expression pattern, in which parentheses have special meaning. Use `indexOf()` instead:

```
alert( elementAction.indexOf("(") );
```

Answer (score 9):

```
elementAction.search("\\(");
```

search is regular expression, ( is keyword in regular expression. you have to escape `(` to `\(`,
`\(` in string is `"\\("`