# Javascript .search() issue Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*/: Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain this bug for me , what we have here is :

```
if(statements[bracket].firsthalf.search(math_operators[j])!=-1)
```

where `statements[bracket].firsthalf = "2*a"` , `math_operators[j]="*"` , the console shows the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*/: Nothing to
>   repeat

any idea why would it show such error ?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript search() fails to find "()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977351/javascript-search-fails-to-find)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `indexOf`, not `search`. `indexOf` looks for literal strings, `search` is for matching a regular expression. In regular expressions, most punctuation characters have special meanings and need to be escaped if you want to find them literally, which is why you're getting errors.

Comment: indexOf is more useful than search in your use. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Search need a RegularExpression as argument.

`*` is used to say 0 or more of the previous expression.

Like `[0-9]*` = 0 or more digits.

To use `*` as a character you have to escape it :

```
\*
```

You have to write the search part as a regular expression.

`2*a".search(*)` is non sense, because it doesn't search the character (`*`) but 0 or more time nothing because there is nothing before the `*`.

It's the same thing for the `+` that is protected character too.

You should use another function than search or write your request in a RegularExpression compliant manner like :

```
search([\*|\+|\-|\/])
```

Comment: but im not searching * as a static value actually * one of values that search will iterate over.

Comment: math_operators=["*","/","+","-"]