# Javascript search() function give Range out of order in character class

Tags: javascript

I am using in string.search("value") to search string. It give SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[sanofi-aventis]/: Range out of order in character class. Below is my code and screenshot.

```
var str = "[sanofi-aventis]";
var res = str.search("[sanofi-aventis]");
```

[image]

Comment: `String.prototype.search()` expects a regular expression as a parameter, not a substring. Why do you need `.search()`?

Comment: I want to search value(e.g. "[sanofi-aventis]" ) from name(e.g "[sanofi-aventis]")

Comment: What does "search" mean in this context? Whether a substring exists in the string? If so: [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: @Ivar thank you for reply..but below is the correct answer and substitute of search()

Comment: this is normal in my opinion because `[sanofi-aventis]` is not a good RegExp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript search() fails to find "()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977351/javascript-search-fails-to-find)

Comment: @Ivar yes I understood the internal working of search(). thank you once again for you concern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because [`String.prototype.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) only accepts a regular expression as an argument, not a string. Your string you provided is an invalid regex. If you want to find it it exists, then just use [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) or [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

```js
var str = "[sanofi-aventis]";

// If value is not -1 then substring exists
console.log(str.indexOf("[sanofi-aventis]") !== -1);  // true
console.log(str.indexOf("foo bar") !== -1);  // false

// Uses ES6 String.prototype.includes, which returns a boolean
console.log(str.includes("[sanofi-aventis]"));  // true
console.log(str.includes("foo bar"));  // false
```

---

A little further info on why `[sanofi-aventis]` throws a range error: that is because it is interpreted as a regex pattern, and the part `i-a` throws the error since the dash between the two square brackets indicates [a character range](https://regexone.com/lesson/character_ranges). Since `i` comes after `a` in the charset, it is invalid.

You will realize that `[sanofa-iventis]` will not throw an error, since `a-i` is a valid character range. However using this in `String.prototype.search` will ***not*** yield the result you expected.